# Vimeo not accessible without log in

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player

I have embedded my Vimeo video with iframe. However, only users with a Vimeo login are able to view the video. I want it to be accessible to all.
Please assist, couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: This is most likely less an issue of the embed code, and more of the privacy settings you made for this video. https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview

Answer (score 1):

Set movie rating (All acessible/Mature content) and after that it will be public.